# Hide elements when API doesn't return any data

Tags: javascript, api, progressive-web-apps

I'm using the Nasa API APOD Astronomy Picture of the Day I want to display the picture and explanation. On 2/3/21 they displayed a video. If they search one date and then search another I want to hide the elements that didn't receive data.
The result I'm getting is once no data is received, the element is permanently hidden instead of only hiding the element that is not received.
The idea was if the data was an image, display the img and hide the iframe. Else if the data is a video display the iframe and hide the image. If I search multiple dates once the element is hidden or display: 'none' the element is now permanently hidden instead of going through the if statement each time a new search is run.

```
// fetch response from api
fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json()) //parse response as JSON
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        // display image in the dom
        if(data.media_type ==='image') {
            document.querySelector('img').src = data.hdurl
            document.querySelector('iframe').style.display = "none"
        // display video in the dom
        }else if (data.media_type === 'video') {
            document.querySelector('iframe').src = data.url
            document.querySelector('img').style.display = "none"
        } else {
            alert('Error, please try again')
        }

        // display explanation of image / video
        document.querySelector('h3').innerText = data.explanation
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(`error ${err}`)
    })
}
```

Data received (object):

```
{
    date: "2021-02-04",
    explanation: "Fifty years ago this Friday.....",
    hdurl: "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image,/2102/a14pan9335-43emj.jpg",
    media_type: "image",
    service_version: "v1",
    title: "Apollo 14: A View from Antares",
    url: "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2102/a14pan9335-43emj_900.jpg"
}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `data`? From what I can see in your code, you're setting the display of the appropriate elements to `none`, but you're not displaying them back once they need to be shown.

Comment: @FiddlingAway ok, I thought that each time they searched a date it would run the fetch and if statement again. The idea was to only display the media received and hide the others so they wouldn't take up any space.

Comment: Do you want the previous results to stay in the DOM, but just be hidden? Or do you want their contents to change / be replaced with newly fetched `data`?  Based on that, things will be done slightly differently - in the first scenario, you'd have to loop through a collection of elements, and know (by some identifier) which ones to hide, and which ones to show. In the second scenario, you would just be replacing the contents, and would not have to loop through anything.

Comment: It would be replacing the previous item. I have an image tag to house the images and an iframe tag for the videos, I used display: none so that they would take up any space when not used. Maybe I could have done this in one html element and eliminated this entire problem and then it would just replace the existing media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code, so that it would display the `img` element if there's an image to be shown, and hide the `iframe`. The opposite applies if there's a video to be shown - you need to display the `iframe` and hide the image.

I've also introduced a CSS class `none`, which is a simple `display: none`. This is to that you can keep the original `display` value set for your elements, and not second guess while you're reverting the display to the previous value. Of course, you don't have to do this, but you might find it easier to manipulate in the long run.

Something like this will work.

```
var image = document.querySelector("img");
var ifr = document.querySelector("iframe");
var info = document.querySelector("h3");

fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json()) //parse response as JSON
  .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      // display image in the dom
      if(data.media_type ==='image') {
          // let's first set the source, and then display the image
          image.src = data.hdurl;
          image.classList.remove("none");

          // let's hide the iframe first, and then remove the source
          ifr.classList.add("none");
          ifr.src = "";
      // display video in the dom
      } else if (data.media_type === 'video') {
          // similar as above - hide first, remove source, and the opposite
          // for iframe
          image.classList.add("none");
          image.src = "";

          ifr.src = data.url;
          ifr.classList.remove("none");
      } else {
          alert('Error, please try again');
      }

      // display explanation of image / video
      info.innerText = data.explanation;
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(`error ${err}`);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, this I understand. I never cleared the old source, and after hiding the elements I never brought them back. So now when the fetch runs it will set the new source, remove the none class, and then add the none class to the unused element and clear the old source. Adding the variables made the code cleaner and easier to write without having to repeat the document.querySelctor  each time.